# Java program using the formula of triangle Area= 1/2*base*height as is

Tags: java

Does anyone knows how to compute for the **Area of a triangle** using this formula in traditional java without changing or adding anything in the formula?

**Area = 1/2*base*height**

If i alter the formula like:

Area = 
1.0f/2*base*heigh  or  1/2.0f*base*height    or  0.5*base*height

...this will definitely give me what I am looking for.

But what I am trying to do is using the formula **Area=1/2*base*height** as is. Someone told me their is a way but I can't seem to follow. 
If this is my program:

public class  Area {

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

         // If this is the given value
         int base = 5;
         int height = 5;
         float Area = 0;

         //Using this formula without altering or adding anything on it
         Area = 1/2*base*height;


         System.out.println("Area = " +Area);
}
```

}

This will give out:

Area = 0.0

*How will I get:

Area = 12.5

Comment: Please use double as your data type.

Comment: `1` and `2` are integers and so `1/2` uses integer division which has an answer of the integer `0`. If you want to remainder it would be `1%2` which would be `1`.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with integer arithmetic. Specifically, consider `1/2`. Because we have int/int, the result must be an int (it can then be cast to a double, float, etc). However, because fractions don't exist in the `int` type, we get `1/2 = 0`. Thus you have `1/2*base*height = 0 * base * height = 0`.

Try `0.5*base*height`, or `1.0/2.0*base*height`, or `(float)1 / (float)2 * base*height`

Specifically, note that in `(float)(1/2)`, the cast occurs too late - you'll get `0.0`.

Comment: So it is called a type cast haha
Thanks a lot men. Your a BIG help!

Answer (score 0):

use double .`int` `int` mathematicians operation,s results  always int in java

```
     double base = 5;
     double height = 5;
     double Area = 0;

     Area = 1.0/2*base*height;
```